# What is the concept to access JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json

My code is like

```
var param="abc";
var data = {abc:1,xyz:2};//json data
console.log(data.abc);
//console.log(data.param);
```

Here m accessing `data` using `data.abc`, its outcome is 1. But when i tried to pass this "abc " using parameter `param` its showing undefined.

Here m not not getting weather it is possible to access `data` using `param` if yes then how???

can somebody help me on this???

Comment: That's not "JSON data". It's a JavaScript object literal.

Comment: There's no JSON in this question.

Comment: Actually m fetching JSON there using ajax call, So i wrote it like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON is simply a serialisation format that uses a text-based subset of JavaScript in a string - using objects in JavaScript isn't JSON (name of it I admit is *slightly* confusing, to say the least).

To do what you want, simply use the square bracket notation:

```
console.log(data[param]);
```

It allows any expression to be placed into it and the return value will be converted into a string, then used to access the property on the object - this allows variables such as `param` to be used dynamically.

For example, here are some results which occur when you're using the square bracket notation:

```
var foo =
    { '[object Object]': 1
    , bar: 2 };
var x = "bar";

foo[{}]; // 1
foo['[object Object]']; // 1
foo.[object Object]; // SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
foo[bar]; // ReferenceError: bar is not defined
foo.bar; // 2
foo["bar"]; // 2 
foo[x]; // 2
foo.x; // undefined
```

Comment: @Sumant Exactly this.

Answer (score 2):

`console.log(data[param]);` Should do it.